# Closed form of infinite product

Tags: closed-form, infinite-product

Is there a closed form solution for the infinite product?
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\bigg) $$

And if so what is it?

Comment: A "closed form solution"? You mean a number?

Comment: Yes, but not simply the decimal value of the above product. For example, the sum of 1/n! from n=0 to infinity is e. I am asking if it is possible to represent the above product as a function of constants in a simplified form(these constants could be pi or e for example)

Comment: If you want funny *approximations* in terms of $e$ and $\pi$, have a look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=express+0.28878809508660242127889972192923078008891190484069+through+pi+and+e

Comment: [OEIS A048651](https://oeis.org/A048651) may help too

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\bigg)=\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }$$ where appears the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Its decimal value is $0.28878809508660242128$

Similarly
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\bigg)=\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)_n$$

Comment: @Servaes. I fully agree with you ! It is a symbol but I do not know any other represntation of this infinite product.

Comment: Using mathematica I obtained the same value. However, is it possiblem to express that value analytically?

Comment: I don't know but Euler's identity $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=1-x-x^2+x^5+x^7-x^{12}-x^{15}+x^{22}+x^{26}-x^{35}-x^{40}+\cdots$$ may be useful for computing it numerically.

Comment: @bof. Yes, for sure ! Stopping at $x^{40}$ this will give a number in error of $4.5 \times 10^{-16}$.